# django tags and html buttons

Tags: django

In my `base.html` I have:

```
    blabla
    {% ifequal alterprofile no %} 
        {% include 'registration/submittedprofile.html' %}
    {% else %}
        {% include 'registration/submittedprofile2.html' %}
    {% endifnotequal %}
    blabla
```

In `views.py` I have `alterprofile = "no"`.
How do i change `alterprofile` to `"yes"`. This is my `submittedprofile`:

```
    <form action="" method="get">
    blablabla
    <input type="submit" value="Make Changes">
    </form>
```

And this is my `views.py`:

```
    def userprofile(request):
        alterprofile = "no"
        username = request.user 
        return render_to_response('registration/userprofile.html', {'user': username, 'alterprofile' = alterprofile})
```

Is there anyone who can code the answers for me. I've tried playing round with the previous answers but to no affect.

Comment: Thanks for updating your question. Please note the correct formatting, which I have changed for you. Also, we need to know what `alterprofile` is. Is it a model instance?

Comment: Sorry missed that in the question. its just a variable

Comment: But where is it coming from? You want to 'change' it, so it must be stored somewhere?

Comment: no its not coming from anywhere, is that my problem

Comment: i want to press a button that will take me from submittedprofile to submittedprofile2. thats all i want. Thus i just created the variable alterprofile so when its yes i go to one and when its no i go to the other

Comment: Ive asked one bad question and bang im banned from ever asking any other questions again. That dosen't seem right to me! Is there any way around this ban. can it be un done

Answer (score 1):

Django variables are rendered from the server side, so you can not change the variable after it was passed to your template. What you want to achieve is done via frontend scripting.

In this case you would pass both variables to the django template, save them in your Javascript and then switch them once you clicked the button you mentioned (via onClick event handling).

Comment: sorry can you give me example, i don't quite understand. P.s. Im not using javascript.

Comment: In reading learning python the hardway and 14chapters of django i have as yet to come across anything to do with frontend scripting. Have as yet to find anything that combines django and frontend scripting on google. Is there any other way i can solve this problem without using frontend scripting

Comment: Frontend scripting will most likely not be covered in the Django book. You have to learn it separately if you want to do dynamic things on your page without reloading the page. Many people call this AJAX (though technically it is not), but it there is the way to start. There a questions on stackoverflow how to use django variables in javascript. See for example this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298772/django-template-variables-and-javascript. Feel free to search for yourself though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use url arguments like:

/myurl/

/myurl/?show2

then, in your views.py you can use request.POST['show2'] to check if exists and then send a variable again to the view to be checked with your {if}s

As an aside note, either you don't understand basic request flow with web applications or you are not explaining properly what you mean with "html button", so you are not fluent with html language. Sorry if my intuition is harsh or wrong.

Answer (score 0):

its not that clear what you are asking but here is how to make the logic work as I think you want it based on yoru submitted code:

in your template change it to 
`ifequal alterprofile "no"` 
to include `registration/submittedprofile.html`.

When you change the view to `alterprofile = "yes"` the `registration/submittedprofile2.html` will be included instead if you keep your current template logic.

This is because in your view, alterprofile is assigned a string therefore its always a string.  When you tried to test against `no` instead of `"no"` django was looking for a variable called no which doesn't exist.

This means that everytime you run it would have always included `registration/submittedprofile2.html`

Comment: yeah, i got that part. It was just an example to highlight that alterprofile was just a simple variable that i want to change back and forth from yes to no and vice versa