# Django template variables in linked javascript

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates

I have javascript in the form `<script src="/static/file.js" />` in a Django template.  I would like this referenced file.js to get the `{{ STATIC_URL }}` and other template variables.

What would be the best way to give access to `file.js` to the template variables?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django Template Variables and Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298772/django-template-variables-and-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Render the desired variables in your main layout file, before you include file.js:

```
<script>
    var STATIC_URL = '{{ STATIC_URL }}';
</script>
<script src="/static/file.js" />
#include other scripts here, STATIC_URL will be available as regular variable
```