# Passing Python Objects to JavaScript through Django Template Variable

Tags: javascript, django, templates, object

I have been able to pass primitive types such as integers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/298793/807089), but I would like to pass more complicated objects, such as some the Django models that I have created. What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: send it to the javascript as json

Comment: Can't you just pass it? As dict (which is json)?

Comment: There's no "correct" way. Just pass what you need as JSON, strings, etc.

Comment: Are there any advantages/disadvantages of converting from an object to JSON on the Python/JavaScript side?

Comment: You want the data. This is the way to do it. So just forget about advantages/disadvantages.

Comment: JSON is the usual choice for sound reasons.  Sometimes you need to do a little extra work to convert more complex Python types, and dates get a little tricky.  But if you have something too complex to embed as a single literal, you'll be better served solving any conversion problems than you will trying to find another method.

Answer (score 3):

I know I'm a little late to the party but I've stumbled upon this question in my own work.

This is the code that worked for me.

This is in my views.py file.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Model

#This is the django module which allows the Django object to become JSON
from django.core import serializers

# Create your views here.
def posts_home(request):
    json_data = serializers.serialize("json",Model.objects.all())    
    context = {
    "json" : json_data,
    }
    return render(request, "HTMLPage.html",context)
```

Then when I'm accessing the data in my html file it looks like this:

```
<script type = 'text/javascript'>
    var data = {{json|safe}}
    data[0]["fields"].ATTRIBUTE
</script>
```

data is a list of JSON objects so I'm accessing the first one so that's why it's data[0]. Each JSON object has three properties: “pk”, “model” and “fields”. The "fields" attribute are the fields from your database. This information is found here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/serialization/#serialization-formats-json

Answer (score 0):

For Django model instances in particular, you can [serialize](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/serialization/) them into JSON and use the serialized value in your template context.

From there, you can simply do:

```
var myObject = eval('(' + '{{ serialized_model_instance }}' + ')');
```

or

```
var myObject = JSON.parse('{{ serialized_model_instance }}');
```

if using [JSON-js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) (which is safer).

For Python objects in general see [How to make a class JSON serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768895/python-how-to-make-a-class-json-serializable)