# how to get a python variable in JS Django

Tags: javascript, python, django

I'm using Django and sending a variable from views.py to my template. How can I get that variable in my JS file?

```
return render(request, 'dashboard/dashboard.html', {"value":123})
```

Now I want to get the `value` variable in my JS file. How can I do it? Inside the template,ie HTML file its easy, just do {{value}} and you get it printed, But I wanted to play with this variable a bit and get it into my JS file. Ho do I do it?

Comment: Include the variable in a `div value_value` & then just do a `get_by_id`?!

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil - Bhai thats a jugaaad (Hope you understands) :D I want something standard. :)

Comment: Have a look at - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298772/django-template-variables-and-javascript?rq=1 I just wanted to show one of the methods (I knew it to be inefficient)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy way it's printing in a `<script>` tag:

```
<script>
  var value = {{ value|escapejs }};
</script>
```

**Edited:**

If you need this var in a separated file you need make a view for render the js file.

Comment: He wants it in his pre-existing scripts which are separately stored from the templates.

Comment: He can use this var in any scope, for example: `namespace.value = value || null;`

Comment: No, no. Never couple JavaScript with Django template language. Makes the code really tightly coupled plus this way clutters the global namespace (window), which is something you really don't want.

Comment: @Carlangueitor - Firstly, Its not working, and yes as Ashish said, I want it in a separate JS file.

Comment: Its still not working. Says `SyntaxError: invalid property id
 

var a = {{ value|escapejs}};`

Comment: @limelights - I agree with you, but here in my code, I want to do the calculations at the client side. Had I been doing at the server -side, I would have easily passed the variable to the template. There's no specific reason for calculating at the client-side. Whats your say. Open for discussion. Thanks

Comment: @Carlangueitor - No No. I cannot do that. isnt there any alternative?

Comment: I can´t Downvote. You can try with {{ value }} (with no filter). But I think that @limelights answer is better.

Comment: Sure, and you can do that, just pass the "start value" to the hidden field and continue to do your calculations in javascript.

Answer (score 3):

Use an input field

```
<input type="hidden" class="hidden" value="{{ value }}" />
```

then your JavaScript

```
var val = document.querySelector(".hidden").value;
```

or you can put it in any html element and query for the value.

Comment: a useful approach is to stick it on a `data-` attribute.  usually when you want to do this the value is related to a particular DOM element anyway.

Comment: Apart from when using the `data-` attribute and you update it via jQuery (for example) then the original value is cached by jQuery so that's a bummer.