# JSON.parse string with single and double quotes?

Tags: javascript, json, escaping

I am saving an array as json and parsing it again upon load. However, after adding HTML with both single and double quotes, this has stopped working.

How can I escape the quotes?

```
JSON.parse('[["",null,null,null,null,null,"","","<span onclick=insertRow()><i class='fa fa-plus-circle fa-lg'></i></span>"]]');

uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

EDIT:

My string is saved in database using JSON.stringify. It ends up in the following format:

```
[["ad",null,true,false,true,false,"","","<span onclick=insertRow()><i class='fa fa-plus-circle fa-lg'></i></span>"]]
```

when Im loading it again, I do it like follows:

```
var phpsave = JSON.parse('<?php echo $result->save; ?>');
```

If im escaping the single quotes before saving, the escaping just dissappears upon loading..

Comment: This has nothing to do with JSON. It's just an invalid string literal.

Comment: How are you encoding the JSON? How are you loading it? You have an issue because you have a string with single quotes as a Javascript literal within single quotes. I doubt that's how you're actually loading the JSON string in practice!

Comment: Why are you using JSON strings at all in JS code, instead of a simple array literal?

Comment: Please see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

You're dynamically producing Javascript source code. You need to ensure that what you're producing is syntactically valid. The easiest way to produce valid Javascript literals from PHP is using `json_encode`:

```
var phpsave = JSON.parse(<?php echo json_encode($result->save); ?>);
// look ma, no quotes!   ^                                       ^
```

But wait, aren't you passing *JSON* to your Javascript? Isn't JSON already valid Javascript? Why, yes, yes it is. So you can leave out that step:

```
var phpsave = <?php echo $result->save; ?>;
```

Of course, you might want to ensure that you're *really* passing valid JSON here first before you start outputting random Javascript code.

Comment: +1 for the proper approach, but [actually JSON isn't always valid JS](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23752156/1048572). And depending on where it is echoed, one still might need to escape things such as `</script>`.

Answer (score -1):

You can escape it like

```
 var r = JSON.parse('[["",null,null,null,null,null,"","","<span onclick=insertRow()><i class=\'fa fa- plus - circle fa- lg\'></i></span>"]]');
```

Comment: If I do that before saving, the \ is gone when loading again. Please see my edit in question.