# Unexpected token : at window.onload

Tags: javascript, api, eval

I'm a beginner in Javascript and I have a little problem with the **eval()** function. So, first I get some data through an API :

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', url, false);
xhr.send(null);
```

So, at that point, I know that **xhr.response** is for example :

```
"{"data":[{"id":41462,"created_at":"2017-11-13 [...]}"
```

Now, I want to make a dictionary with it, so I do :

```
var req = eval(xhr.response);
```

But the console shows me *"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : at window.onload"* at the **eval()** step. And I don't know really why... any tips ?

Comment: Use `JSON.parse()` instead of `eval()`

Comment: that looks like JSON instead of doing eval do JSON.parse(xhr.response) it will work

Comment: Me thinks your JSON isn't valid.

Answer (score 2):

`eval` expects to be passed a chunk of JavaScript. A JSON representation of an object is not (by itself) valid JavaScript.

To parse JSON, use `JSON.parse` and not `eval`.

Comment: Surely any valid JSON will also be parsed as valid JS? Not trying to be contrarian, but do you have an example of valid JSON, but not valid JS?

Comment: @evolutionxbox not always.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23752156/are-all-json-objects-also-valid-javascript-objects

Comment: @Amy good to know. A̶l̶t̶h̶o̶u̶g̶h̶ ̶I̶ ̶d̶o̶n̶'̶t̶ ̶t̶h̶i̶n̶k̶ ̶i̶t̶ ̶s̶a̶t̶i̶s̶f̶i̶e̶s̶ ̶O̶P̶'̶s̶ ̶e̶r̶r̶o̶r̶.̶ 
 Nevermind... it does.

Comment: Thank's a lot! I didn't know about JSON, you're helpful :)

Comment: @Quentin ooooo. Interesting