# Pass array of dicts from python to Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, django

I am not able to access an array of dicts passed from python script to javascript. When I use the following code, there is no alert message popping up. What am I doing wrong here?

```
errors = [1, 2]
graphs = [{'A': 1}, {'B': 2}]
return render(request, 'index.html', {'errors': errors, 'graphs': graphs})

# index.html
<script>
if ({{ graphs }}){
    alert('Detected');
}
if ({{ errors }}){
    alert('Detected');
}
</script>
```

I even tried converting this to json, but still same problem.

```
mygraphs = json.dumps(graphs)
return render(request, 'index.html', {'errors': errors, 'graphs': mygraphs})
```

I am able to access the array fine inside the HTML.

```
{% for graph in graphs %}
    <li style="color: red;">Element detected</li>
{% endfor %}
```

prints out `Element detected` twice. But I am not able to do this inside the script.

Comment: try `if ("{{ graphs }}")`

Comment: Sorry, doesn't work..

Comment: try `console.log("{{ graphs }}")`

Comment: Nope, no comment printed to console..

Answer (score 0):

Django template replaces single quotes by `&#39;` entity.  So add the `safe` filter to the `graphs` variable:

```
if ({{ graphs|safe }}){
    alert('Detected');
}
```

Comment: I think it produce `undefined` error. `"{{ graphs }}"` should be needed.

Comment: I had already tried this...it did not work. Maybe I should add that even using the `errors` array does not popup the alert

Comment: I tested it right now and it works just fine.  The rendered html is: `if ([{'A': 1}, {'B': 2}]) {`

Comment: So did you get the alert message?

Comment: Yes, I got the alert.  Just in case I am using firefox.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
if("{{ graphs|safe }}"){
    alert('Detected');
}
```

Refer this [Django Template Variables and Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298772/django-template-variables-and-javascript)

Comment: Sorry, did not work. Also see my edit, I don't think `safe` has anything to do with it, even a simple array `errors` is not detected.

Comment: "safe" is for convert `&#39` to back only. I just tested here.Did you try without `json.dumps`