# How to pass the argument to the external javascript via django view

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I want to pass the argument to the javascript via the django view.

I always separate the js code and html code into two files, index.html and index.js.

Here is the django view

```
def index(request):
    template = loader.get_template('index.html')
    context = RequestContext(request,{'name':'guest'})
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

I have the index.html like this

Access the argument name in index.html is ok.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
{% load staticfiles %}
<script> 
var name='{{ name }}'
console.log(name) //guest
</script> 
<script src="{% static "js/index.js" %}"></script>
</body>
```

But in the external index.js, I can not access the argument.

```
var name ='{{ name }}'
console.log(name) //'{{name}}'
```

How can I pass the argument or variable to the external javascript?

Thank you!

Comment: you cannot! You could call the function that you need from the html file and this way you can pass the parameter or you should put the value in an hidden element in the DOM and then read it from the external js file

Comment: There are many solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298772/django-template-variables-and-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You've already made the `name` variable available globally in the script block in index.html. You can just refer to it directly from any other piece of JS as `name`.

Comment: So I have to explicitly make a global variable in the index.html? What if I want to just past the argument to the external js file directly?

Comment: I don't understand your question, sorry.

Comment: Sorry for my explanation, Is it possible to pass argument to the external js without assigning any global variable in html files?