# Pass Json from Django to template with JavaScript Staticfile

Tags: javascript, json, django

I am trying to pass a json from django to a template html file with javascript staticfile.

view.py

```
import json
def view(request,...)
...
    return render(request,'index.htm',"g1":json.dumps({"id":1,"name":2})
```

index.html

```
<head>
<script language=javascript" src="/static/myapp/myscript.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="init();">
<div>I am here</div>
</body>
```

myscript.js

```
var json = {{g1}};
function init(){
}
```

myscript.js is not working. Without {{g1}} statement in .js file, it works. Please help.

Comment: How are you expecting that to work? myscript.js is a static file, it doesn't parse template variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe the variable will be passed into the myscript.js. You have to add the js inline within the template to get it:

```
<script>
var json = {{g1}};
function init(){
}
</script>
```

Also according to other stackoverflow answers, this may be vulnerable to injection attacks if you do not use this:

escapejs filter:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#escapejs

safe filter:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#safe

Other sources:
[Django Template Variables and Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298772/django-template-variables-and-javascript/1187881#1187881)

Comment: Note that `init()` could still be in the separate JS file, and refer to the global `json` variable.

Comment: Thanks Hieu and Daniel.