# using Django Template Variables in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-templates

I'm writing an app that needs dynamic javascript. I didn't know how to use Django template variable in javascript. when I searched I found some answeres like 
[Django Template Variables and Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298772/django-template-variables-and-javascript)
but I still have the problem.
when I write this piece of code in my html :

```
        <script>jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
           $(".nav").css({"opacity": "0.5"});
           $("#description").animate({opacity: '+=0.5'}, 10000);
           });
        </script>
```

every thing is fine. the navbar is transparent and `<p id="description">{{description}}</p>`is shown by jquery animate function. but when i change it to this:

```
      <script>jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
           $(".nav").css({"opacity": "0.5"});
           var a = "{{description}}";
           $("#description").animate({opacity: '+=0.5'}, 10000);
           });
      </script>
```

the navbar is no more transparent and the description is no more shown.
what is the problem ?

p.s : I changed a to a = "{{blah}}"; and there is no problem with it. the problem apears when It is a real template variable.

Comment: The javascript you've included is pretty much no different between code examples, You have an unused variable containing a string of `description` but other than that its the same

Comment: but when I define this unused variable the script does not work any more. that is my problem.

Comment: Are you using angular.js or something else that uses the same django syntax? adding unused variables shouldn't affect anything

Comment: i don't use Angular.js. I just use Jquery.

Comment: when I change a to a = "{{blah}}"; there is no problem. so it understand that it is a template variable but then it is failed to continue. i don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

Use [verbatim](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#verbatim):

> Stops the template engine from rendering the contents of this block
>   tag.
>
> A common use is to allow a JavaScript template layer that collides
>   with Django’s syntax. For example:
>
> ```
> {% verbatim %}
>      {{if dying}}Still alive.{{/if}} 
> {% endverbatim %}
> ```