# Using context variables as javascript parameters

Tags: javascript, python, django

I'm working on a project in Django, for part of it I'm trying to use Googles chart api, which uses a Javascript function to plot the graph. So what I'm trying to do is generate the graph data in my views.py and then pass the data through the context variables to the script. To test this I tried to do:

```
graphplot = [['Age', 'Weight'],[ 8,      12],[ 4,      5.5],[ 11,     14],[ 4,      5],[ 3,      3.5],[ 6.5,    7]]

context = {
    "graphplot": graphplot,
}
```

in my views.py then I have:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable({{graphplot}});
```

in my template, however this doesn't seem to work.

When I do:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['Age', 'Weight'],
  [ 8,      12],
  [ 4,      5.5],
  [ 11,     14],
  [ 4,      5],
  [ 3,      3.5],
  [ 6.5,    7]
]);
```

It does show the graph so I know it's not a problem with the JavaScript.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: "_this doesn't seem to work_". What _does_ it do?

Comment: It just doesn't display the graph on the webpage, which I assume is because the JavaScript failed.

Comment: That's not useful information. What output does `var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable({{graphplot}});` produce?

Comment: Sorry I'm very new to this, it doesn't seem to produce any output.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/25538871/20128

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, It should work.

```
var plot_data = {{graphplot}};

var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(plot_data);
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Try to print console.log(plot_data) , and check what is it printing?

Comment: Hi, I think I've worked out the problem but I'm not sure how to fix it. When Django renders the page the tag is rendered as: var plot_data = [[&#39;Age&#39;, &#39;Weight&#39;], [8, 12], [4, 5.5], [11, 14], [4, 5], [3, 3.5], [6.5, 7]]; so it seems to be rendering the ' character incorrectly.

Comment: Try this: var plot_data = {{graphplot|safe}};
LEt me know is this worked?

Comment: Welcome  :), safe is a built in django filter.  Can you please vote up