# Django: using context variable in a script

Tags: javascript, python, django

I have a class view that inherits from `TemplateView` and sets a context variable to a serialized list of items:

```
class MyView(TemplateView):
  def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(MyView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['items'] = serializers.serialize("json", items) # assume items is an existing list
    return context
```

As is noted in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298772/django-template-variables-and-javascript) you're supposed to be able to access Django variables from our Django templates in the following manner:

```
<script>var items = {{ items }};</script>
```

However I am getting a JavaScript error, which I assume is caused because of automatic escaping:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &
```

I also tried using the filter:

```
<script>var items = {{ items | escapejs }};</script>
```

Only to find another error, this time a Django one (`TemplateSyntaxError`):

```
Could not parse the remainder: ' |  escapejs' from 'items | escapejs'
```

How can I solve this issue?

PS: I am using Django 1.4. (and no, I cannot upgrade it to the most recent version).

Comment: try using {{ items|safe }}

Comment: Instead of passing the json through the template to your script you could add an endpoint view which serializes the data you need and request this from javascript itself with something like `$.getJSON("your_view_url", function(data) { }`

Comment: @SebastianBurzyński I get the same error than with `escapejs`: `Could not parse the remainder: ' | safe' from 'items | safe'`

Comment: @JackEvans that's what I initially did, I ajax'ed the items as JSON in another request, but it seems redundant now, since I can do it all in just one request.

Comment: As Daniel said, you cannot use spaces in between your "|" sign.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use spaces between a template variable, the filter character, and the filter itself. So it should be `{{ items|escapejs }}`.

Although as Sebastian points out, you probably want `{{ items|safe }}` instead.

Comment: Oh wow that was it. Can you explain what were the whitespaces causing? And why should `safe` be used instead of `escapejs`?

Comment: The template parser is pretty basic, it just isn't clever enough to deal with spaces there. `escapejs` adds additional escaping for characters that have meaning in JS; you want the opposite, ie to pass the JSON exactly as is without escaping.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
  var items = "{{items}}";

</script>
```