# How to insert python value into a Django HTML template?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

In Django, I have an HTML template where I would like to insert values 
for some javascript variable.

```
<html>
  var jsvar=  {{ Python_Django_String_VAR}}
</html>
```

In Django View:

```
   return render(request, pageurl, context)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django Template Variables and Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/298772/django-template-variables-and-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

This questions was duplicate another title.
For beginner of Django, I put the answer to be useful :

The {{variable}} is substituted directly into the HTML. Do a view source; it isn't a "variable" or anything like it. It's just rendered text.

Having said that, you can put this kind of substitution into your JavaScript.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
   var a = "{{someDjangoVariable}}";
</script>
```

This gives you "dynamic" javascript.