# Django instert utf8 text in textarea editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, html

I have a utf8 text that I'm trying to insert into a textarea. The code is pretty simple:

```
let initial_description = "{{ initial_decription }}";
$("#descripcion").html(initial_description);
```

But I get this error:

> SyntaxError: unterminated string literal

Comment: Presumably the content of `initial_decription` contains double quotes, which then breaks your Javascript...

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298772/django-template-variables-and-javascript which highlights the dangers of this approach and offers some alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

most likely in your `{{ initial_decription }}` exist quotes.

You can bypass the error by preloading data in hidden field.

Like This:

```js
let initial_description = $("#initial_description").val();
$("#descripcion").html(initial_description);
```

```html
<input type="hidden" id="initial_description" value="{{ initial_decription }}">
```