# How to compare Django template language variables with javascript variables?

Tags: javascript, django, jinja2

I've got something like this in my Django template:

```
<script>
var selected_direction = $("#id_direction").val();
{% for bus_stop in bus_stops %}

     {% if bus_stop.direction == selected_direction %}
        // Do something //
     {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
</script>
```

I can do everything with bus_stops until it reaches the {% if %} statement. How can i compare javascript variable with django variable?

/Edit

Maybe the question was not constructed properly. However i solved my problem by doing this:

```
<script>
var selected_direction = $("#id_direction").val();
var temp_direction;
{% for bus_stop in bus_stops %}
    temp_direction = "{{ stop.direction }}";
     if (temp_direction == selected_direction){
        ////////
        ///////
     }
{% endfor %}
</script>
```

Comment: What are you even trying to do? Django is run on the server side. None of your client side code has been run yet at that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298772/django-template-variables-and-javascript) that explains how they work together. There is a injection risk involved with this. Maybe make an ajax call for your data and do everything in javscript.

Answer (score 2):

you can compare this condition

```
{% if bus_stop.direction == selected_direction %}
```

by converting you template value to js value, and compare it in js if condition as follows.

```
if(selected_direction == '{{bus_stop.direction}}')
{
  //code here
}
```