# Get Django variable in HTML template with Javascript part

Tags: javascript, html, django

Happy new year to everybody ! I would like to get your help because I'm thinking how I can rewrite a little part from my code.

I have a `django variable` sets in my context and I pick up this variable in my `HTML template` (especially in my `JavaScript` part in my HTML template).

It works, but it's not a good idea because I would like to set all JS in one JS file and don't have piece of JavaScript in each HTML template.

**In Django I have :**

```
submethods = SubMethod.objects.all()
submethods_item = []
for item in submethods:
    submethods_item.append({'id': item.id, 'text': item.name})
context['submethods_item'] = submethods_item
```

**In my HTML template, I have this piece of JavaScript :**

```
function get_sub_method_options(keep_cur) {
  var sel_option = $('select#id_method-group').find("option:selected");
  var sel_val = sel_option.val();
  if (!sel_val) {
    $("select#id_method-sub_method").empty();
    let all_sub_methods = {{ submethods_item|safe }};
    for (var i = 0; i < all_sub_methods.length; i++) {
      $("select#id_method-sub_method").append('<option value="' + all_sub_methods[i].id + '">' + all_sub_methods[i].text + '</option>'); //here add list of all submethods
    }
    return;
  };
  ...
}
```

As you can see, I get the Django variable here :

```
let all_sub_methods = {{ submethods_item|safe }};
```

How I can make the same things, but with a method which let to write JS in my JavaScript file containing Django variable ?

If I write in my HTML template :

```
<script>
   let all_sub_methods = {{ submethods_item|safe }};
</script>
```

And I write my JS part inside an external file .js, it should work right ?

Thank you !

Comment: So you know how to do this, but instead of simply trying it, you decided to post a lengthy question here? Why? Also, there's another way: create an endpoint in Django that sends JSON and request it via AJAX / fetch().

Comment: @ChrisG because by asking, it helps anyone else with a similar problem, and as you have demonstrated, there might be other solutions.

Comment: @SpoonMeiser [But there's this already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript). I do know that dupes can be useful, but how many do we need?

Comment: I'm not sure why you have JS here at all. Why not just create the option list in the Django template?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django Template Variables and Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298772/django-template-variables-and-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach might work, but only by accident.

Your context variable `submethods_item` is a Python list containing dictionaries. If you use that variable in a template with the `safe` filter, it gets rendered as a string that is valid JavaScript, but there are many ways this can go wrong.

The recommended approach is to serialize your variable to JSON, apply the `escapejs` in the template and then parse it in JavaScript.

```
# view
import json
...
context['submethods_item'] = json.dumps(submethods_item)

# template
<script>
   let all_sub_methods = JSON.parse("{{submethods_item|escapejs}}");
</script>
```

Comment: I will try your method and I will come back soon ! Thank you very much @Daniel Hepper

Comment: It seems to work fine ! Thank you very much for your explanation !