# how to make messages showed up in the template

Tags: javascript, django, templates

i have a login django app where i am trying to inform user in if they have wrong credentials  or if they are successfully login.

the problem is that i used the message framework in django but it did not showed up in the template.

## views.py

```
from django.contrib import messages


def login_request(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST['lognName']
        password = request.POST['lognCode']
        user = authenticate(username = username,password = password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request,user)
            messages.info(request,f"You are now logged in as {username}")
            return redirect("main")
        else:
            messages.error(request,"invalid username or password")

    return render(request,'login.html')
```

## login.html

```
{% if messages %}
    {% for message in messages %}
        <script>M.toast({html:"{{message}}",classes:'blue rounded',displaylength:2000});</script>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

even if i tried to used outside the if statement the toast doesn't work

Comment: Did you see html in page source code?

Comment: @daniherrera  it display this error Uncaught ReferenceError: M is not defined

Comment: It looks like a JS issue. Where do you declare M?

Comment: @daniherrera yes you were right i did not import the js library.

Comment: I post the comment as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the script inside
`$(document).ready(function($) { /* foreach message M.toast(...) */ });`

I will personally do it in a separate js file.

If you want to access to the messages object from js check out this link: [Django Template Variables and Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298772/django-template-variables-and-javascript)