# How to Access Context Variables Sent from Django Application in Javascript

Tags: javascript, django

I have sent a variable in context from my django python code as so:

```
context = {
    "data": data,
}
return render(request, "template.html", context)
```

but do not know how to access it in my javascript file. I have tried accessing it like this:

```
data_from_django = {{ data }}
```

However this simply gives me a syntax error. Please can someone tell me the correct way to access this variable.

Comment: Have you tried ```data_from_django = {{ data|safe }}```?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django Template Variables and Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298772/django-template-variables-and-javascript)

Comment: use this: data_from_django = "{{ data|safe }}". If you don't use quotes, javascript will consider it as variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IN Javascript you have to use the variables within the quotes.

```
data_from_django = '{{ data }}'
```

if "data" is a JSON value, be sure to use {{ data | safe }}

In the case where variable and javascript code is not in the same html file,the above method will fail.

In the case of separate js file, wrap the variable with a id and later refer to it in the js file:

//template.html

```
<div id="data_from_django">{{ data }}</div>
```

//sample.js

```
var data_from_django = 
document.getElementById("data_from_django").innerHTML;
```

Comment: Do I have to do anything in `template.html`?

Comment: Just to note that wrapping the variable in a div will work but I think it has security issues