# assign result of comparison to variable javascript

Tags: javascript, pycharm, comparison-operators

If I do that:

```
var importance_not_matched = {{item.this_article_importance}} <= article_importance;
```

It seems to work but in my IDE (Pycharm) I have errors:
"Expression expected" on the "<="
and 
"underterminated statment" on the final ";"

I'm using flask, item.this_article_importance is an int

I solved my issue by changing to:

```
year_not_matched = {{item.this_article_year <= article_year}};
```

I don't understand why it's better yet though

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the type of value that is `{{ item.this_article_importance }}` you may have to use filter `|safe`, so that django does not escape it.

Something like this:

```
var importance_not_matched = {{ item.this_article_importance|safe }} <= article_importance;
```

You can verify that both variables really have the desired value, even the type, to ensure where the error comes from.

```
var this_article_importance = {{ item.this_article_importance|safe }};
console.log(typeof(this_article_importance), this_article_importance);
```

It's hard to know more without more information. You can review this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298772/django-template-variables-and-javascript) where the topic is discussed.

Comment: I think it wasn't that because I disabled autoescaping. But your answer will help me in the future I think

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by changing to:

year_not_matched = {{item.this_article_year <= article_year}};

I don't understand why it's better yet though