# Sending to JS data from Python and getting response back

Tags: javascript, python, canvas, python-imaging-library

so I am trying to send JS data, to be more specific, images responses Python file has collected, I need from python to send these images to JS and JS does a thing, (which I'll be coding) and sends the final result back to Python, how possible is that? I have 0 idea of doing that, looking forward for help, :cheers:

Answer (score 1):

You can use API for the process. Post request & get request and so on. Also  in Django you can deal with this process. Send variables from views.py and from template you can use them. There is similar question: [Django Template Variables and Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298772/django-template-variables-and-javascript)

Comment: I see, I am not that experienced in Django specifc, But I'll try that, and what API were you mentioning at first?