# Django template var in Javascript

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates

Let's take a dictonary:

```
mydict = {
  'color': "blue",
  'brand': "Ford",
  'year': 1969
}
```

We pass this dict to our template, then, in the template, we have a select list with options according to our dictionary keys (color, brand, year).

Now, I want to change some text in my rendered template regarding the selected option.

So we have some Jquery that is getting the value of the selected option, like this:

```
$('#myselect').change(function() {
        var selected = $( "#myselect option:selected" ).text();
    });
```

Now that we have the selected text, I would like to use it as a key to display a value from our dictionary.
Something like this

```
$('#myselect').change(function() {
            var selected = $( "#myselect option:selected" ).text();
            $('#mytext').text('{{ mydict.selected }}');
        });
```

But I guess mixing Django var and JS var like this, is not going to work...
Any idea how I can do this ?

Comment: You can use html5 dataset attribute and get the value via JavaScript/jQuery. That's the cleanest method if you ask me.

Comment: Best to try something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/25538871/1638231

Answer (score 0):

Based on Martins comment, here is what I did:

In the template:

```
<select id="myselect">
  <option value="color">color</option>
  <option value="brand" selected="">brand</option>
  <option value="year">year</option>
</select>

{% for key,value in mydict.items %}
  <small id="{{key}}" class="messages" style="display:none;">
    {{ value }}
  </small>
{% endfor %}
```

Then some JS:

```
$('#myselect').change(function() {
        var selected = $( "#myselect option:selected" ).text();
        $('.messages').hide();
        $('#' + selected).show();

    });
```