# Django for loop in JavaScript syntax error

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-models

I am trying to use Django for loop in JavaScript but I am getting a syntax error:

```
<script>
        var config = {
        type: 'pie',
        data: {
            datasets: [{
                data: [1780000, 1630000],
                backgroundColor: [
                    '#ff0000', '#0000ff', '#ff0080', '#73ffff', '#5c26ff', '#002db3',       '#ffff26', '#4cff4c', '#ff00ff'
                ],
                label: 'Population'
            }],
            labels: [{% for label in labels %} {{ label }}, {% endfor %}]
        },
        options: {
            responsive: true
        }
        };
</script>
```

this part is what i a have a problem with to be exact

```
{% for label in labels %} {{ label }}, {% endfor %}
```

just typing:

```
{% for %}
```

gives me a syntax error
I looked at similar stack overflow questions and they just use the for loop normally without any problems so why am I getting a syntax error. I even tried it in an an empty Js file and still get a syntax error.
Am I forgetting to import something? It works just fine in the HTML file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't directly use Django template tags in your JavaScript code. You can use them in your template files.

Please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298772/django-template-variables-and-javascript) to understand how to access them from JavaScript code.

Comment: Thank you for kindly replying and referencing that question. I just had to put `{{ label }} ` between 2 quotations and the code works perfectly but it is not optimal especially for numbers and still has syntax errors. Looks like using JSON is the correct proper way.

Comment: Yes, if JS code is placed in a template file then it works. However, it is better to keep JS code is in its own files. Yes, using JSON might be a better idea, if you don't have to use template tags. You're welcome.