# How to use getElementById in django

Tags: javascript, html, django

I'm trying to generate a code for editing posts using modal that are made before
but it shows "Identifier or string literal or numeric literal expected" and "Statement expected" ERROR
here is my code:

`

```
function submitHandler(){
       const textareaValue = document.getElementById("textarea_"${post.id}).value
</script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"onclick=submitHandler({{post.id}}) > Save Changes</button>
```

`

want to submit change to editing posts.

Comment: Maybe this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298772/django-template-variables-and-javascript) can help you.

Answer (score 0):

if your are sending the *textarea* id via onclick, so didn't need to get it again via jinja or django template.

```
<script>
   function submitHandler(post_id){
   my_textarea = 'textarea_'.concat(post_id);  
   const textareaValue = document.getElementById(my_textarea).value
</script>

<button type="button" class="btn" onclick=submitHandler({{post.id}})> Save Changes</button>
```