# How to pass a list of dates from Django ORM to a javascript date list to use as labels in chart.js

Tags: javascript, python, django

I'm trying to plot some charts comparing the close price of pairs of stocks in a timeline.

My Django view.py function looks like this:

```
    # Access stock pairs for the user settings
    stock_pairs = StockPair.objects.filter(setting=setting)

    # Create a context dictionary including, for each stock_pair in stock_pairs, the close prices of the stocks in the pair and pass the dictionary to the template
    context = {}
    stocks_and_pair_data_list = []
    for stock_pair in stock_pairs:
        stocks_and_pair_data = {}
        stocks_and_pair_data['stock1_name'] = stock_pair.stock1.name
        stocks_and_pair_data['stock2_name'] = stock_pair.stock2.name
        stocks_and_pair_data['dates'] = [dt for dt in stock_pair.stock_pair_data_set.values_list('date', flat=True)]
        stocks_and_pair_data['stock1_close_prices'] = [float(close) for close in stock_pair.stock1.stock_data_set.values_list('close', flat=True)]
        stocks_and_pair_data['stock2_close_prices'] = [float(close) for close in stock_pair.stock2.stock_data_set.values_list('close', flat=True)]
        stocks_and_pair_data_list.append(stocks_and_pair_data)
    context['stocks_and_pair_data_list'] = stocks_and_pair_data_list
    
    return render(request, 'my_page.html', context)
```

and my_page.html has this script section:

```
    <!-- For each stocks_and_pair_data in stocks_and_pair_data_list create, using chart.js, a chart of the close prices of stock1 and stock2 -->
    {% for stocks_and_pair_data in stocks_and_pair_data_list %}
        <script>
            const ctxClose = document.getElementById('ChartOfClosePrices{{ forloop.counter }}');

            new Chart(ctxClose, {
                type: 'line',
                data: {
                    labels: '{{stocks_and_pair_data.dates}}',
                    datasets: [{
                        label: '{{ stocks_and_pair_data.stock1_name }}',
                        data: '{{stocks_and_pair_data.stock1_close_prices}}'
                    },{
                        label: '{{ stocks_and_pair_data.stock2_name }}',
                        data: '{{stocks_and_pair_data.stock2_close_prices}}'
                    }]
                }
            });
        </script>
    {% endfor %}
```

I'm having 2 problems. The first problem is that I get the following error on the browser for each stocks_and_pair_data:

`SyntaxError: Identifier 'ctxClose' has already been declared`

The second problem is that the x axis doesn't show the dates in a proper format. Instead the axis shows values that doesn't mean anything to me, like

> [ a e i e d t ( 0 2   0 ) a e i e d t ( 0 2   0   ) (and so on...)

So how to name ctxClose dinamically so they don't conflict with each other and what am I doing wrong when I'm passing the data from the view function to javascript so the date axis is shown properly?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions that may help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use the variables from "views.py" in JavasScript, "<script></script>" in Django Template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298772/how-to-use-the-variables-from-views-py-in-javasscript-script-script-in) Note: From a security standpoint I'd specifically suggest the answers that use `json_script`. I'd recommend against the answer below here as well for the same reason.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the list to JSON and just put it in the template

```
for stock_pair in stock_pairs:
    stocks_and_pair_data = {}
    stocks_and_pair_data['stock1_name'] = stock_pair.stock1.name
    stocks_and_pair_data['stock2_name'] = stock_pair.stock2.name
    stocks_and_pair_data['dates'] = [dt for dt in stock_pair.stock_pair_data_set.values_list('date', flat=True)]
    stocks_and_pair_data['stock1_close_prices'] = [float(close) for close in stock_pair.stock1.stock_data_set.values_list('close', flat=True)]
    stocks_and_pair_data['stock2_close_prices'] = [float(close) for close in stock_pair.stock2.stock_data_set.values_list('close', flat=True)]
    stocks_and_pair_data_list.append(stocks_and_pair_data)
stocks_and_pair_data_list.stock1_close_prices = json.dumps(stocks_and_pair_data_list.stock1_close_prices)
stocks_and_pair_data['stock2_close_prices'] =json.dumps(stocks_and_pair_data['stock2_close_prices'])
context['stocks_and_pair_data_list'] = stocks_and_pair_data_list

return render(request, 'my_page.html', context)
```

In the template

```
 chart.data = {{stocks_and_pair_data.stock2_close_prices}}
```